# Indexed words missing in the output pdf. Motivation is missing. How to fix this?

Tags: indexing

```
\documentclass[12pt] {book}

\usepackage{makeidx}       % follow try index format makeidx and hyper ref together
\usepackage{hyperref}   

\makeindex    % 17 Nov 2014 
\begin{document}

My main \index{motivation} is to address the plunging state of the education


\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you run `makeindex` after compiling the file and then compile it again? Also, you probably want `\index{motivation}motivation` in the text?

Comment: Yes I did. I generated the .ind file with zero errors. Then I typeset Latex on TS.

Comment: And then you recompiled the `.tex` file? When I compile your code, I get the index. I have to add the word to get it in the text, but I get the index.

Comment: The main problem is that the pdf output has lost the indexed word. It should be there in the first place. Thanks cfr..

Comment: I got it. You leave the original text alone. It works. Thanks

Comment: Yes. Of course, you can use a support package or define some new command yourself which will both index the term and print it in the text.

Comment: @cfr An answer?

Comment: @egreg Er... OK. Is this really not a duplicate?

Answer (score 6):

If I compile your code as it is using `pdflatex` -> `makeindex` -> `pdflatex`, I get the index produced fine:

[image: index]

However, this probably isn't quite what you want in the main text of the document:

[image: missing word]

`\index{motivation}` adds `motivation` to the index. That's it. It does not also typeset the word in the text. So, you probably want something like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt] {book}

\usepackage{makeidx}       % follow try index format makeidx and hyper ref together
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeindex    % 17 Nov 2014
\begin{document}

My main \index{motivation}motivation is to address the plunging state of the education


\printindex

\end{document}
```

which gets you the term in the index *and* the text:

[image: restored word]